# 403 error after setting up vhosts

Tags: linux, apache, centos, vhosts

I am running a CentOS 6 server (on Digital Ocean) which has apache 2.2 installed.

I installed ProFTP and have set up a user called 'rator' with whom I can ftp in to the home directory at /home/rator/

I want this directory to be a working web development environment and have set up a further two sub dirs - dev and stage.

In the dev folder I have cloned my git repo and have ended up with the rather long path:

/home/rator/dev/rator/

I want to set up a vhost to this directory. I have set up my hosts file for rator.dev on my local machine, and have the following in the vhosts section of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@email.com
    DocumentRoot /home/rator/dev/rator
    ServerName rator.dev
    ErrorLog rator.dev-error_log
    CustomLog logs/rator.dev-access_log common

    <Directory /home/rator/dev/rator>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to view this in the browser - I get a 403 error. "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

If I chown apache:apache all of the dirs and files below /home/ then the site becomes visible however, I then cannot log in through ftp as the ftp home dir is then owned by apache and I'm logging in as 'rator'.

I have tried many variants on the Vhosts directory permissions but so far have not been able to solve the access problem.

Does anybody know what the correct vhosts should be here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turned out to be pretty dumb....

sudo chmod o+rx /home/rator

Execute and read permissions were not set correctly on the home folder....